# Python thread termination requirements / is join(ing) required and neccessary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, thread-safety, python-multithreading

Hey I'm working on a python project that makes considerable use of threading for various things, whether it be timing events or handling different events/IO/messages and I want these threads to terminate correctly and not hang around after task completion.

1. Is `.join()`ing a thread absolutely necessary? Or can I just let it finish processing it's task and forget about it?
2. A continuation of 1, if on a regular thread I am required to `.join()` does setting a thread to daemon change that? I know setting a thread as daeemon makes the thread exit when the main thread exits regardless of if it is in the middle of doing something or using other resources and that is bad practice as it doesn't clean up nicely, but does it change anything else like somehow allow the thread to just exit upon completion of it's task?
3. If `.join()`ing is not necessary (for scenarios 1 and/or 2) then is `.join()`ings only purpose, or only really necessary when you want to block processing in a thread to wait for another thread to finish?
4. Can threads be joined from any other threads or do they have to be joined back into their direct parent/the thread that spawned them and/or the main thread?  Because if `.join()`ing is necessary I thought about creating a housekeeping thread that would just go around joining any finished threads that need to be joined to be fully terminated.

I ask because I have a considerable amount of threads being spawned (from other child threads) either waiting on IO or as non blocking timers to set off other threads. Keeping track of all these threads is already a considerable amount of work and then having to join them all sounds like a nightmare. I was hoping I could just let them finish or that by marking threads as daemons they would terminate as soon as they finished and that's that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do threads in python need to be joined to avoid leakage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38275944/do-threads-in-python-need-to-be-joined-to-avoid-leakage)

Comment: Yea, I think that answer just about answers my question, Thank you!  I'm not sure why I didn't come across it when searching.  Do I close out my post now?  Do you want to comment with a link to that post and I can vote it as the answer?